# What is the "Input Method" application used for?

Tags: 14.04, input-method

"Input Method" or "Im-Config" is an application installed by default on 14.04. What does it do? What do people typically use it for? Why did ubuntu see it as necessary to install by default on their distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The im-config command provides the framework to configure the input method on X Window System. This input method is the essential mechanism for Japanese, Chinese and Korean (CJK) languages to enter their non-ASCII native characters.

FYI: For any command you want to know the purpose of, you can open a terminal and type `man COMMAND_NAME`. Example: To find the information I posted above, I opened up a terminal, entered `man im-config`, and then pressed `Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to what @amanthethy wrote that im-config is basically a feature behind the scenes which users, including users who need special input methods, don't normally access directly. The input method selector provided by *Language Support* is typically sufficient.